# How to send an email to multiple recipients and hide their addresses using Play Mailer

Tags: scala, email, playframework, mailer

I am using [Play Mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) with Scala, and I am trying to send the same email to multiple recipients. Is there any way to send my email to multiple recipients separately which means that a recipient cannot see the addresses of the other recipients ? Here is the code used to send the same email to a sequence of emails, so the recipients can see all other addresses in the `TO` field.

```
import play.api.libs.mailer._
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.json._

class MailerApi @Inject() (mailerClient: MailerClient) extends Controller {
  def sendEmail = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val subject: String = (request.body \ "subject").as[String]

    val cid = "1234"
    val email = Email(
      subject,
      "ExcelWay <email1@gmail.com>",
      Seq("Miss TO <email2@gmail.com>",<email3@gmail.com>),
      // adds attachment
      attachments = Seq(),
      // sends text, HTML or both...
      bodyText = Some("A text message"),
      bodyHtml = Some("content")
      )
    mailerClient.send(email)
    Future.successful(Ok("ok !!"))
  }
}
```

Comment: already tried, but it hide only the cc, in my case I don't want to use cc I want that every recipient receive the email as if he is the only recipient, which means that in the To field he can see only his address email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice to send a mail to several recipients without them knowing there are other recipients is to send an email to yourself and add all your recipients as BCC.

Add this to your `Mail` object :

```
bcc = Seq("email1@domain.com", "email2@domain.com")
```

and set the `TO` field with your own mail address.

Comment: I thought about that, but in the field "To" I want that recipient see his email not mine

Comment: The recipient will see his own email. Try it out :)

Comment: I tried and the recipient see only my address email

Comment: Huh! I think you will not get closer to what you want with the `play-mailer` except if you send a new email for each recipient.